# регулярка на php, как распарсить переменную на отдельные части

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Буду рад вашей помощи, т.к не особо силен в регулярных выражениях, было бы неплохо если кто-то помог бы с ней.

Дано есть текст в переменной типа string:

> ActionType ("Name<0><IDENTIFER_1:10000>")

Мне нужно вытащить в отдельные переменные всю информацию из строки.

- ActioneType (обычный текст, название действия и его типа)
- Name<0>
- IDENTIFER_1:10000
- other

для примера чувствительные данные изменил но суть отображает.

Comment: какое-нибудь такое https://regex101.com/r/O7pIFP/1

Answer (score -1):

Не совсем понял, что должно быть в "other", но вот пример для остальных частей строки:

```php
$m = null;
$str = 'ActionType ("Name<0><IDENTIFER_1:10000>")';
if(preg_match('/^([^\( ]+) \("([^<]+<\d+>)<([^>]+)>"\)$/', $str, $m)){
    echo '<pre>', print_r($m,true), '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: достаточно бы было использовать нежадный поиск вида `.+?` и обойтись без этих вот `[^...]`